# How do I encoding my java web start application title on JRE7?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, jnlp

I have a JWS Application and it's title is Chinese. It works fine on jre6. But on jre7, it don't encode shortcut title on windows 7(or Windows XP) correctly, The Java Cache Viewer dialog and Certification Dialog both have the same problem.

How do I encoding my java web start application title on JRE7?

The content of JNLP file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="localhost:9080/xmaker/">
        <information>
            <!--  chinese title -->
            <title>课件录制工具</title>
            <vendor>XXX</vendor>
            <shortcut online="true" install="false">
                <desktop/>
            </shortcut>
            <offline-allowed/>
        </information>
        <security>
            <all-permissions/>
        </security>
        <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
        <resources>
            <java initial-heap-size="134217728" version="1.6+"/>
            <!-- some other jar resources -->
        </resources>
        <application-desc main-class="xxx.xxx.xxx.RecorderToolMain"> </application-desc> 
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: I have tried to encode it as UTF-8 and declared encoding as utf-8 on the top of my jnlp file. But the problem is still occured.

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP now.  Post it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15375968/edit).  Be sure to validate the JNLP with [JaNeLA](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15375968/edit).

Comment: The content of JNLP file as follows:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://localhost:9080/xmaker/">
  <information>
    <title>课件录制工具</title>
    <vendor>XXX</vendor>
    <shortcut online="true" install="false">
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java initial-heap-size="134217728" version="1.6+"/>
    
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="xxx.xxx.xxx.RecorderToolMain">

  </application-desc>
</jnlp>

Comment: Put is as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15375968/edit)!

Comment: Thank you for your help, Andrew. I have posted jnlp code in question. And I have tried to add **java-vm-args="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"** attribute to <java> tag, but no effect.